# Cassandra - MATERIALIZED VIEW working 1 out of 3 times

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra and wanted to use Materialized view to change the way I expose my data but It works sometimes and doesn't some other times.
So I wondered, does anyone as an idea of why such a thing could occur?

Here is the exact script I am running (in a docker container)

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS demo3 WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };

/*
** Drop view to allow droping table
*/

DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS demo3.tabletest_view;

/*
** TABLE demo3.tabletest (
**  cardKey text, fidelity card key
**  dateKey Date, date of the transaction
**  kind text,
**  power text,
**  sid text, //avro schema id
**  data blob,
**  PRIMARY KEY ((cardKey), dateKey, kind, power)
** ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (cardKey, trxDate DESC);
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo3.tabletest;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo3.tabletest (
    cardkey text,
    datekey date,
    kind text,
    power text,
    sid text, 
    data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((cardkey), datekey, kind, power)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (datekey DESC);

/*
** FIXTURES
*/

INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-05-01', 'kind1', 'power1', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-05-08', 'kind1', 'power2', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-05-09', 'kind2', 'power1', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-05-15', 'kind1', 'power3', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-05-22', 'kind1', 'power4', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-05-25', 'kind2', 'power2', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-05-30', 'kind1', 'power5', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-06-06', 'kind2', 'power3', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-06-14', 'kind2', 'power4', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2016-06-17', 'kind2', 'power5', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );

INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-05-01', 'kind1', 'power1', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-05-08', 'kind1', 'power2', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-05-09', 'kind2', 'power1', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-05-15', 'kind1', 'power3', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-05-22', 'kind1', 'power4', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-05-25', 'kind2', 'power2', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-05-30', 'kind1', 'power5', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-06-06', 'kind2', 'power3', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-06-14', 'kind2', 'power4', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2016-06-17', 'kind2', 'power5', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );

INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-05-01', 'kind1', 'power6', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-05-08', 'kind1', 'power7', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-05-09', 'kind2', 'power6', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-05-15', 'kind1', 'power8', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-05-22', 'kind1', 'power9', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-05-25', 'kind2', 'power7', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-05-30', 'kind1', 'power10', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-06-06', 'kind2', 'power8', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-06-14', 'kind2', 'power9', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card1', '2017-06-17', 'kind2', 'power10', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );

INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-05-01', 'kind1', 'power6', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-05-08', 'kind1', 'power7', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-05-09', 'kind2', 'power6', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-05-15', 'kind1', 'power8', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-05-22', 'kind1', 'power9', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-05-25', 'kind2', 'power7', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-05-30', 'kind1', 'power10', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-06-06', 'kind2', 'power8', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-06-14', 'kind2', 'power9', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );
INSERT INTO demo3.tabletest ( cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data) VALUES ( 'card2', '2017-06-17', 'kind2', 'power10', 'Id', bigintAsBlob(99) );


/*
** DISPLAY RESULT:
*/

SELECT * FROM demo3.tabletest;

/*
** Creating view
*/

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW demo3.tabletest_view 
AS SELECT cardkey, datekey, kind, power, sid, data 
FROM demo3.tabletest
WHERE cardkey IS NOT NULL AND datekey IS NOT NULL AND kind IS NOT NULL AND power IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ((cardkey), datekey, kind, power);

SELECT * FROM demo3.tabletest_view;
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: your table and view have same Primary key... not a cause of error but just a fyi. It is serving no purpose. Whatever query you run on materialized view you can run on base table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting data from MATERIALIZED VIEW `tabletest_view` right ?
It's because of tabletest_view is build in progress. When you create MATERIALIZED VIEW on top of a table with existing data, It needs some time to build and data propagation.

Meanwhile you’re able to get the current status of all view through

```
 SELECT * FROM system.views_builds_in_progress ;
```

and a list of all built view by executing

```
SELECT * FROM system.built_views ;
```

When your view is built you will get data.

Comment: Thx, we came to the same conclusion